# Grep returns “No such file or directory” in bash script , works manually

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I am getting "grep: Filename: No such file or directory" while running bash .sh script.

Command are running manually. File type is "ASCII text, with very long lines". Is this causing issue?

```
overall_row_count=$(grep -c "^000[1-5]" $filename)
trailer=$(awk 'substr($0,0,4)=="T999" {print}' ${filename})
overall_trailer_count=$(echo "${trailer:29:8}" | sed 's/^0*//')
if [[ ${overall_row_count} == ${overall_trailer_count} ]]
      then 
      echo "Count matches"
      else echo "Count doesn't match"
fi
    
p=53
for i in {0001..0005} 
do 
row_count=$(grep -c "^$i" $filename)  
trailer_count=`echo "${trailer:$p:7}" | sed 's/^0*//'`
p=`expr $p + 7`
if [[ ${row_count} -eq ${trailer_count} ]]; then
    echo "Count matches."
else
    echo "Count doesn't match"
fi
done
```

set -x output

```
++ grep -c '^000[1-5]' BB.CD.20210502.DAT
grep: BB.CD.20210502.DAT: No such file or directory
+ overall_row_count=
++ awk 'substr($0,0,4)=="T999" {print}' BB.CD.20210502.DAT
awk: fatal: cannot open file `BB.CD.20210502.DAT' for reading (No such file or directory)
+ trailer=
++ echo ''
++ sed 's/^0*//'
+ overall_trailer_count=
+ [[ '' == '' ]]
+ echo 'Count matches'
Count matches 
+ p=53
+ for i in '{0001..0005}'
++ grep -c '^0001' BB.CD.20210502.DAT
grep: BB.CD.20210502.DAT: No such file or directory
+ row_count=
```

++ echo ''
++ s

Comment: In addition to the suggestions in the answer, it would help if you also added the script invocation to your question. How exactly is it launched? Plus, ensure that `$filename` is the same name as when you use `grep` manually.

Comment: yes, i am using same filename along with filepath

Comment: If you use exactly the same name, and your working directory is the same as the script's working directory, you should get the same result. As alluded to in the answer, the working directory is probably not the same. Add `pwd` to the script to see its working directory.

Comment: you were right, working directory was not same. I've fixed that and now code is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: This is great. Please mark the answer as correct (and, if you feel like it, upvote it).

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely that your problem would be long lines in the text files.

More likely, your script is running in a context that changes the working directory or otherwise alters the content of $filename in a way that is coming as a surprise.

Have you tried putting set -x in your script to see exactly what the content of $filename is at the time of execution? That might provide some clues.

Adding a pwd command to your script might also give you a clue.

If that doesn't get you on the right track, please update your question to include  the information you get from my above suggestions and it might be possible to provide some more targeted suggestions.

Comment: yes, it was due to working directory, i 've updated the path and now code is working correctly. Thank you.

Comment: @Mini Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problems where `grep` was finding nothing, in my case was due to me creating a path variable as `dir="~/git/Marlin"`, after use `grep foo $dir/bar` error appeared, to fix it I had to change to `dir="$HOME/git/Marlin"` and that fixed it.